# Is the centroid method implemented in MySQL spatial?

Tags: mysql, spatial

Simple question, I'm wondering if the centroid method is implemented in the MySQL spatial extensions.  I've looked at the documentation but wasn't able to find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 7):

In general: Yes

MultiPolygon: No

> The OpenGIS specification also defines
>   the following functions, which MySQL
>   does not implement:
>
> Centroid(mpoly)
>
> Returns the mathematical centroid for
>   the MultiPolygon value mpoly as a
>   Point. The result is not guaranteed to
>   be on the MultiPolygon.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/geometry-property-functions.html#function_centroid

You can get the centroid of each polygon, within a multipolygon, though this is not documented in the MySQL manual, by using the `geometryn` function. For exmaple,

```
select astext(centroid(geometryn(geomfromtext('MultiPolygon(((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0)),((10 10,10 20,20 20,20 10,10 10)))'),2)));
```

returns

```
POINT(15 15)
```

which is the centroid of the 2nd polygon within the MultiPolygon. It probably doesn't make much sense for a MultiPolygon to have a centroid, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can read it from the [MySQL - Polygon Property Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html). Look below the page for the first user comment. It says there:

> there are more than just these functions available. I think this not
>   clear enough in the docs. for example, the MultiPolygon 'Centroid'
>   function works for Polygons as well.

Example:

```
mysql> SET @poly = 'Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))';
mysql> select astext( Centroid(PolygonFromText(@poly)));
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Mysql 8 centroid is not there anymore.

The proper solution to get the center of the polygon|m-polygon is `st_centroid()` method.

Here is an example:

```
select st_astext(ST_Centroid(st_geomfromtext('MultiPolygon(((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0)),((10 10,10 20,20 20,20 10,10 10)))'))) as center_point;
```

The reference [Mysql st_centroid() method](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/gis-polygon-property-functions.html#function_st-centroid)